# Forecasting daily usage of a prouct

Tags: predictive-modeling, bigdata, regression, time-series, hierarchical-data-format

Lets say that you have panel data, of **daily consumption of product p1 of 10000 individuals.** The panel data is on a daily basis for only one month, this means that $t=1,...,30$. 
The question is how do it ? What kind of model I to use and why.

My answer iss to have a two-level model:

$y_{i,t}=\beta_{i}x_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}$

$\beta_{i}=\gamma_{i}z_{i} + \eta_{i}$

where $x_{i,t}$ would contain my **time variant** variables and $z_{i}$ will contain all my **time invariant** variables. My argument was, that by modeling it like this, I believe that I take control of the time dependency between the $y_{i,t}$ and $y_{i,t-1}$ by letting the $\epsilon_{i,t}$ **also depend on time** and also I capture the heterogeneity of the consumers. Where $\epsilon_{it}\sim N(0,\Sigma_{\epsilon})$ and $\eta_{i}\sim N(0,\sigma_{ \eta _{i}}^2)$

What do you think ?